# How to create navigation menu in xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can i create one navigation menu for whole project.
I created one but for specific view only using SWRevealViewController.
[image]

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: i want to create one slide menu that i can open from any view in my project

Comment: ok , where you struck

Comment: i don't know how to do that i created menu but for only one view

Comment: ok remove the connection, use connection less, add the progrmatic navigation  in didselect in SWL rear page

Comment: welcome bro.....

Comment: programatic navigation already in didselect in SWL rear page

Comment: show the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in two ways.

a) Create a ViewController with side menu and subclass the view controller every time you need a side menu.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(funcToCall))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    }
 }
```

and subclass `BaseViewController`

```
class MyViewController: BaseViewController {
}
```

b) Another method and the better one is using `extension`

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addMenu() {
      let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)))
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    }
}
```

and call addMenu() in `MyViewController`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       addMenu()
    }
}
```

One of the many ways is to create a swift file `Helper.swift`

then

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func addMenu() {
      let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)))
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand solution b where i put this part
    extension UIViewController {
    func addMenu() {
      let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(funcToCall))
       navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    }
}

Comment: what funcToCall do and where to put it

Comment: Please see the code. I adjusted for your use. Replaced `funcToCall` with `SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)`

Comment: it worked with me thanks a lot solution b saved my time.

Comment: Glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your RevealVC with navigation controller and add navigation item to RevealVC, but such a menu will be static.

I usually use TopViewController class:

```
class TopViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth = view.frame.size.width / 2
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }

}
```

Each view controller will just inherit this options. In this case you should create navigationVC in storyboard for each view controller (I think it's the best solution). Do not forget to drag outlets from storyboard to TopViewController.

Creating only one NavigationVC is impossible i suppose.